# Есть ли в WebPack библиотека или настройка, чтобы он не импортировал не нужные функции?

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, npm

Например, если в файле file.js есть функция fun1 и fun2, если я импортирую в файл app.js одну из них в тут же вызываю ее, в итоговый файл попадает и вторая функция, которую я не хотел и не импортировал. Если это одна функция - то ничего страшного нет, но если я импортирую модуль где 30 функций, хотя нужны мне только условно две, так почему бы не импортировать только нужные?
В минифицированном файле уже нет лишних функций, есть ли способ убрать их сразу из обычного?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вам нужен плагин [Tree-Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) в webpack.