# Какая зависимость правильная для установки typesript и других модулей?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Подскажите пожалуйста правильно ли я определил, что эти пакеты должны быть в Dependencies? как научиться понимать куда устанавливать пакет в Dependencies или devDependencies. Если я случайно включу все пакеты в Dependencies по ошибке, увеличится ли размер моей сборки? Может ли компилятор удалить ненужные пакеты?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте это, тут максимально подробно всё расписано https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies/22004559#22004559

Comment: "Может ли компилятор удалить ненужные пакеты?" - Весь пакет не уверен, но неиспользуемый код "Да" https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1485634/385375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понять куда какие зависимости ставить не сложно. Достаточно взглянуть на название.
Например:

**devDependencies** - говорит о том, что сюда устанавливаются те зависимости, которые нужны при разработке, то есть, запуска сборки **в режиме dev**.

**dependencies** - говорит о том, что сюда попадут те зависимости, которые будут в окончательной сборке, **в режиме production**

Если рассматривать ваш случай, то `jest` вам нужен только на этапе разработки, поскольку используется для тестирования приложения.

Такая же ситуация и с `typescript`, при сборке приложения, `файлы ts` конвертируются в `файлы js`. Таким образом, можно понять, что он тоже относится к `dev` зависимостям.

`Babel` точно также должен отправится в `dev` зависимости.

Компилятор не сможет удалить ненужные. Чтобы так было нужно поставить [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/). Он поможет избавиться от ненужных файлов.